# Android: php non-associative array output with blob field to sqlite

Tags: php, android, json, sqlite, blob

from a PHP Script I get the a non-assoziative array output

```
...
$data[8] = base64_encode($data[8]..
.
.
array_push($CuNames, $data);
echo json_encode($CuNames);
```

the fields in the MySql Table are Name varChar(30), Country varchar(5), PicHome Blob, FuzzyHome varchar(3).

```
 [["Manne","Swiss", "KDKJJRNNN\KSHFHAAA....",null],["Adam","USA","HKKKHJIIDD\jkJ\jk.....",null]]
```

Is there a way to ignore the Blob Data in the http Stream and extract only the Fields
Name, Country, FuzzyHome and put it in a JSON Array,
Is it possible to get the Blob Field PicHome from the http Stream in a JSON Object or JPG or other format so I can use it in a sqlite table as Blob Field and how to do this.
Don't ask about perfomance and other things. The PHP is a given Script and not my Baby and it can't be altered by me. I know there are solutions with two http Streams one for Data and one for the pict...

Comment: yes they are constant (field positions)